# Duplicate records being pulled from SQL 2008 query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following tables -

```
**TimeLogs**
ID
UserID
JobID
TimeTaken

**Jobs**
ID
EstimatedTime
ActualTime

**ClockInLogs**
ID
UserID
ClockDateTimeIn
ClockDateTimeOut
```

The following query generates duplicated records -

```
SELECT tl.JobID, TimeTaken as 'HoursSold',
DATEDIFF(minute, ClockDateTimeIn, ClockDateTimeOut) / 60 as Hours_Difference,
DATEDIFF(second, ClockDateTimeIn, ClockDateTimeOut) / 60 as Minutes_Difference
from TimeLogs tl
INNER JOIN Jobs j on tl.JobID = j.ID
LEFT JOIN ClockInLogs cil on tl.UserID = cil.UserID
where tl.UserID = 10000 and 
    ClockDateTimeIn BETWEEN DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,'11/08/2013'), 0) AND 
    DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,'11/08/2013'), 6)
    group by tl.ID, tl.JobID, j.TotalEstimatedCharge, tl.TimeTaken, cil.ClockDateTimeIn, cil.ClockDateTimeOut
```

[image: Screenshot of duplicate records]

What I would like it to do is return a sum of HoursWorked, Hours_Difference and Minutes_Difference - without the duplication. I can't work out where the duplication is coming from. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to sum those values up for?  Just JobID, or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to sum the hours and minutes instead of grouping by them:

You could end up with more than 60 minutes doing it this way.

```
select
    tl.JobID, 
    TimeTaken as 'HoursSold',
    Sum(datediff(n, ClockDateTimeIn, ClockDateTimeOut) / 60) Hours_Difference,
    Sum(datediff(s, ClockDateTimeIn, ClockDateTimeOut) / 60) Minutes_Difference
from 
    TimeLogs tl
        inner join
    Jobs j 
        on tl.JobID = j.ID
        left join
    ClockInLogs cil 
        on tl.UserID = cil.UserID
where 
    tl.UserID = 10000 and 
    ClockDateTimeIn between dateadd(wk, datediff(wk,0,'11/08/2013'), 0) and
    dateadd(wk, datediff(wk,0,'11/08/2013'), 6)
group by 
    tl.JobID, 
    tl.TimeTaken
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say for certain without seeing the data, but I suspect you are grouping by fields that should be summed instead (TimeTaken, ClockDateTimeIn, and ClockDateTimeOut):

```
SELECT tl.JobID,
SUM(TimeTaken) as 'HoursSold',
SUM(DATEDIFF(minute, ClockDateTimeIn, ClockDateTimeOut) / 60) as Hours_Difference,
SUM(DATEDIFF(second, ClockDateTimeIn, ClockDateTimeOut) / 60) as Minutes_Difference
from TimeLogs tl
INNER JOIN Jobs j on tl.JobID = j.ID
LEFT JOIN ClockInLogs cil on tl.UserID = cil.UserID
where tl.UserID = 10000 and 
    ClockDateTimeIn BETWEEN DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,'11/08/2013'), 0) AND 
    DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,'11/08/2013'), 6)
group by tl.JobID
```

Note that I also removed the group by for fields not in the select because this would create the appearance of duplicates as well.